Android Appium - WebDriver exception while having explicit wait
I am doing mobile testing using java, selenium, cucumber and junit frameworks, i have a feature file having 2 scenarios positive and negative, my code runs the positive scenario very well, but the same code in negative scenario it will run until the explicit wait funcion applied. when it found the wait it throws the WebDriver exception
[31morg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
